# PHP: spl_autoload_register attempting to load files from wrong directory

Tags: php

I am trying to implement autoloading of my classes. I separate my classes into two different folders:

```
/classes
/external
```

In my `external` folder, I keep everything third-party that I am using within my application. It may include classes, functions, etc. I like to keep that separate from my own code.

I want to include everything in the `external` directory manually. I only want files in the `classes` directory to be autoloaded. Here is what I have:

Files:

```
/classes/cache.class.php
/classes/db.class.php
/classes.mail.class.php
/external/hooks.php
```

And to autoload:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/'.$class_name.'.class.php';
});

$Cache  = new cache();
$Db = new db(); 
$Mail = new mail();
```

Somehow, this is attempting to load any class that exists in the `external` directory. I know this because in `hooks.php` I have:

```
class Hooks { ... } // Notice the capital H
```

And I am getting the error:

"Warning: include(/path/to/classes/Hooks.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

How can I get `spl_autoload_register` to ignore all classes that exist outside of the `classes` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/classes/.$class_name.'.class.php'))
```

right before your include

Comment: Thanks. I just don't understand why it's searching in other directories and not staying in the one specified. Can you explain why?

Comment: Because you aren't showing the whole code especially the code that calls `spl_autoload_register` ,  I can't give you a good answer.  Most Likely whatever calls it is got a preset list to try first.

Answer (score 2):

The autoloader has no way of knowing in which folder a class is defined.  The general flow is:

- See an undefined class being used in the code being executed
- Call all the functions registered with the spl_autoloader, and pass them the undefined class name

Since you didn't have any check for if the file exists, the autoloader function you registered is erroring out whenever you fail to include a non-autoloaded class before it's used.  As @Forbs mentioned in his answer, just add a check in your autoloader function to see if the file exists before including the source file.

It's worth noting that Composer does this job for you very well already - unless you have some specific reason for wanting to use your own autoloader, I'd suggest just setting up composer for your project.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md